# 'Clang-Tidy: Do not implicitly decay an array into a pointer' when using std::forward and const char*

Tags: c++, c++11, clang-tidy

I do not understand why Clang-Tidy produces the error `Clang-Tidy: Do not implicitly decay an array into a pointer`  in the following example:

```
struct Foo {
  explicit Foo(std::string _identifier) : identifier(std::move(_identifier)) {}

  std::string identifier;
};

struct Bar {
  template<typename... Ts>
  explicit Bar(Ts &&...args) : foo(std::forward<Ts>(args)...) {} // <-- Error

  Foo foo;
};

Bar bar("hello world");
```

From the error I understand that `"hello world"` being an array of type `const char[11]` (or similar) is decayed to type `const char*` somewhere during `std::forward`. But why and how can I fix this error? `std::make_shared<Foo>("hello world")` is very similar regarding usage of `std::forward` and does work.

Comment: Have you tried `Bar bar((char const *)"hello world");` ? Does it still show error? Although it is not a nice fix, still it is interesting if it fixes the problem.

Comment: This does not trigger the error as the cast is eventually an explicit decay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bogus diagnostic. I would disable it globally, since this usecase is so common.

Comment: Yup, seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

> From the error I understand that `"hello world"` being an array of type `const char[11]` (or similar) is decayed to type `const char*` somewhere during
> `std::forward`

`"hello world"` is a `char const[12]` and decays to `char const*` when you
construct a temporary `std::string` to call `Foo`'s constructor.

> But why and how can I fix this error?

A way to suppress that warning is:

```
Bar bar(std::string{ "hello world" });
```

> `std::make_shared<Foo>("hello world")` is very similar regarding usage of `std::forward` and does work.

This is interesting:

```cpp
Foo foo0("hello world"); // No warning
auto foo1 = std::make_shared<Foo>("hello world"); // No warning

Bar bar0("hello world"); // Warning
auto bar1 = std::make_shared<Bar>("hello world"); // Warning
```