# How can I decay const char that is passed as reference to a function with variadic parameters?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, cpp-core-guidelines

I have a function like this:

```cpp
void column(const std::string &value) { ... }

void column(float value) { ... }

template <class... TColumns> void row(const TColumns &...columns) {
  ImGui::TableNextRow();
  (column(columns), ...);
}
```

I am using clang-tidy static analyzer to make sure that my code is always compliant with cpp core guidelines. I am using this function in the following way:

```cpp
// (const char[5], float)
row("Hello", 20.5f);
```

My understanding is that, `std:string` accepts `const char *` but the first argument of the function call above gets inferred to `const char[5]`. This causes array decay and I get clang-tidy error that:

> do not implicitly decay an array into a pointer; consider using gsl::array_view or an explicit cast instead

Is it possible to somehow enforce that string argument that is passed is always `const char *`, not `const char[5]` or `const char[6]` etc?

Comment: How about turning off this warning? Any solution provided here will be inferior to simply writing what you mean. Coding standards should always be used with caution and common sense.

Comment: Also, make it a `static const std::string hello = "Hello";` if you use it multiple times... or simply take a `string_view` in `column` if you don't need ownership.

Comment: _A string literal is a `const char[]` in C++_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356223/assign-a-string-literal-to-a-char

Comment: The type of `"Hello"` is `const char[6]`.  If you want a different type deduced, you'd need to specify what that type is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Clang-Tidy: Do not implicitly decay an array into a pointer' when using std::forward and const char\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72101801/clang-tidy-do-not-implicitly-decay-an-array-into-a-pointer-when-using-stdfo)

Comment: You could add a `template <std::size_t N> void column(const (&value)[N])` overload to work with string literals directly and not convert them to a `std::string` which might do a dynamic allocation.

Comment: @NathanOliver Is there a way to decay this from character array to character pointer? The thing is, in the implementation of a function, I am using a funciton that accepts `const char *`. So, I can‘t directly use that either.

Comment: You would have to do an explicit cast like `static_cast<const char*>("hello")`

Comment: You could use Nathan's suggestion to forward the C string literal to the std::string function: `template <std::size_t N> void column(const (&value)[N]) { column(std::string(value)); }`

Comment: You could also add `// NOLINT` to the end of the line to disable clang-tidy warnings on that line.  Although i agree that this warning should be disabled.

Comment: @Iorro I like having the warnings for other cases where decaying matters but it has drawbacks like character arrays complaining about array decay. So, I just disabled it for this particular line without needing to disable it globally.

Comment: Another option is to use `using namespace std::string_literals; row("Hello"s, 20.5f);` and now `"Hello"s` is a `std::string` literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you anyways convert a c-string to a string *each time* you reach this line, it's suggested to have a `static string`. That is expected to solve the warning as well.

```
#include <iostream>

void column(const std::string &value) { }
void column(float value) { }

template <class... TColumns> void row(const TColumns &...columns) {
  // ...
  (column(columns), ...);
}

int main() {
    static auto hello = std::string{"Hello"};
    row(hello, 20.5f);
}
```

However, the best solution is likely to simply turn off the warning - either globally, or as Drew wrote, via `// NOLINT`.